# Decorate all SymPy outputs to Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, sympy, jupyter, python-decorators

Whenever SymPy outputs a `float` back to Jupyter notebook, it displays the whole number with the best precision that it could muster. I find this difficult to work with as an engineer, who is used to reading numbers at multiple-of-3 powers of 10 (nano, micro, milli, kilo, mega, giga, etc.)

I have written a custom function `to_engg()` that takes a number and returns a string containing a number in an arbitrary precision and the engineering prefix tacked on at the end.

How do I intercept the SymPy output and process it first through my `to_engg()` function?

> **SymPy:** Okay, now I'm going to spit out this ugly float `65722045.8015267`
>   **Me:** Not so fast. Go through `to_engg()` first.
>   **SymPy:** `ptui!`
>   *Some magic happens here*
>   **Jupyter:** Here you go. `65.7 M`

The most generalized way I could think of doing this is via decorators, so that I could use just any other function aside from `to_engg()`.

Answer (score 1):

SymPy supports arbitrary precision levels, so you could start with numbers that are the precision you want, like `Float('10.3', 3)`.

Otherwise, you'll need to create a custom printer that subclasses `sympy.printing.latex.LatexPrinter` and overrides `_print_Float` to use the precision you want (see the [default implementation](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/3364138879de0ea98f2df313f56ada03c13163f9/sympy/printing/latex.py#L311)), and use `init_printing(latex_printer=YourSubclass().doprint)`.